# Select HtmlToPdf - Html page saved in development and not saved but shown in production

Tags: select, html2pdf

I've got a problem with saving and NOT displaying a page that I want converted to pdf. The code I use works fine from within Visual Studio but not from IIS. On the development machine it converts the HTML page, saves the pdf and then redirects. On a 'production' machine with IIS it shows the html page (FactuurPDF) but stops there.
What I want is the behaviour on the development machine.
This is my code:

```
// other stuff

HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
var TxtUrl = "";
TxtUrl = "https://localhost:44368/Facturen/FactuurPDF" + "?id=" + id + "&fact=" + fact;

PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl(TxtUrl);             
var dat = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
doc.Save(@Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Verzondenfacturen/Fact_" + id + "_" + dat + ".pdf"));
doc.Close();

//other stuff (email pdf and update database)
return LocalRedirect("/Facturen/Index");
```

I hope anybody has a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `converter.Options.MaxPageLoadTime = 10` solved the problem.